# Show $Df(z)(y_0-x_0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Show that the **mean value theorem** for a real function on a convex domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $f$ be a smooth fucntion on a domain $D \subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x_0$ and $y_0$ and the line segment connecting them belong to $D$. There is a point $z$ in this line segment such that the derivative of $f$ at $z$ in direction $y_0-x_0$ is zero, i.e.,

$$Df(z)(y_0-x_0)=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

As stated the claim is not true, I assume what you meant is $Df(z)(y_0-x_0)=y_0-x_0$. Hint in this case: apply the ordinary mean value theorem in one variable to the function $\varphi:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ defined by $$\varphi(t)=f((1-t)x_0+ty_0)$$